# how to replace only the first whitespace in string with a dash with regexreplace in google sheets?

Tags: regex, whitespace, regexp-replace, removing-whitespace

Trying to replace:
`"abcd efgh ijkl"` with `"abcd-efgh ijkl"`
in google sheets.
I tried:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C5,"(?:[A-Za-z]+)(\s)","\-$1")
```

but it doesn't work. I think I'd need to use beg/end anchors (^$)but this failed too.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Capture the leading part and put it back in the replacement:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C5, "^(.*?)\s", "$1-")
```

This captures everything between the start to the first whitespace, consuming the whitespace, and replaces it with the captured content and a dash - effectively replacing the space with a dash.

The important part of the regex is the `?` after `.*`, which makes the `.*` *reluctant*, which matches as *little* as possible. As opposed to plain `.*`, which matches as *much* as possible (ie *greedy*).